# How to fill up global arrays inside a function in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a global array:

```
buffer = []
```

I am trying to assign the values of this array from a function:

```
def data():
    temp1=5
    temp2=6
    global buffer
    buffer[0]=temp1
    buffer[1]=temp2
```

However, this doesn't seem to work and the values aren't getting updated in the global array. Eclipse doesn't even seem to parse these statements. Any help? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: is `Data():` the function? You need a `def`statement to declare a function, also usually you don't usually use uppercase for method names in Python according to PEP8.

Comment: ^^ I just wrongly typed it here. Function and syntax - all are proper in the code :) Thanks!

Comment: You just defined a function but call the function for working on array/list.

Answer (score 0):

To have **gloabal**s is almost always bad idea, you should modify your function to accept the array/list in its parameter list, like so:
(I'we renamed variable buffer to my_buffer for clarity)

```
my_buffer = []

def data(buffer):
    temp1=5
    temp2=6
    buffer.append(temp1)
    buffer.append(temp2)


data(my_buffer)

# prints out  [5, 6]
print(my_buffer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the code you've shown, you never end up calling your function.

You have to have the following line at some point after you define `data`:

```
data()
```

You do not need to declare `buffer`as a `global` inside your function since you aren't reassigning it. `buffer[0] = temp1` is going to find the global `buffer` variable through normal name lookup, and call it's `__setitem__` method. The operation is done in place, so the reference is not reassigned.